# How to use CommandExt methods in rust

Tags: rust, process

Running rust on fedora 33

```
stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.51.0 (2fd73fabe 2021-03-23)
```

I am trying to use some methods in https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/process/trait.CommandExt.html. It is a `Trait` that has been implemented by `Command` struct, but the compiler cannot find the corresponding methods:

```
        let mut cmd = Command::new(target)
            .args(args);
        cmd.pre_exec(|| {});
```

Error:

```
40 |         cmd.pre_exec(|| {});
   |             ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `&mut Command`
```

I suspect I need to `cfg` the `target_os` to instruct the compiler?

Comment: Did you *import* the trait? `use std::os::unix::process::CommandExt;`

Comment: thanks, explicitly claiming `use std::os::unix::process::CommandExt;` resolves the issue.
But I don't quite understand why this Trait needs to be imported explicitly..

Comment: *All* traits need to be in scope in order to use them independent of the concrete type (glossing over those added in automatically in the [std prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html))

Answer (score 0):

One needs to explicitly import the trait:
`use std::os::unix::process::CommandExt;`.
This is required because `CommandExt` is not part of https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html